# echoing a checkbox inside an echoed form

Tags: php

I have an echo of a form and for the echo of a radio button I use this:

```
//works fine.
value='0' ";if ($row["werkverwijder"] == '0') {
echo "checked";
}
```

for a textarea I use this:

```
//works fine.
".$row["overmij"]."</textarea></td>
```

But when it comes to a checkbox I'm at a complete loss.
This is what I tried:

```
value='1' "; if($row["fav"] == 'checked')
{
echo "checked";
}
```

but it doesn't work. I tried a whole lot of other combinations but still not getting anywhere.

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Why is everyone giving me minus points instead of an answer? If it is so simple you could also help :-)

Comment: show the generated html...

Comment: already solved it, but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided much code so it's difficult to say anything, it should work.
Note SPACES:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sth" <?php if($row["sth"] == "checked"{echo "checked";})?> >
```

Check the developer console for any errors.

Comment: Thank you, I found the error, it was totally unconnected, so now everything works. I'm a woman and blond :-)

Comment: Glad you got it working :) Good luck on your further PHP adventures :D

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to ask more sophicated questions in the future :-)